# how to loop over array of objects and get values from object- ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, foreach

I need to loop over this and add this to form data.

```
"SHOCKS" = [{
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "GBPUSD",
  D0: 0.3,
  D1: 0.3,
  …
}, {
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "KRWUSD",
  D0: 0.3,
  D1: 0.3,
  …
}, {
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "AUDJPY",
  D0: 0.08,
  D1: 0.08,
  …
} {
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "AUDKRW",
  D0: 0.08,
  D1: 0.08,
  …
}, {
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "AUDMXN",
  D0: 0.08,
  D1: 0.08,
  …
}],
```

I'm doing like below.

```
let FxShock = FxList["FXVOLBUMP"].SHOCKS;
let FxShocksAll1 = Object.entries(FxShock).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value}`));
```

But I'm getting `undefined`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I recommend taking some to structure your question so it is clear what you are asking for help with? Formatting your code as code blocks would help everyone understand. I would recommend reading the 'How do I ask a good question?' guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm _getting_ undefined?" Are you seeing undefined in your `console.log` statements? Or are you referring to the fact that `FxShocksAll1` will be undefined? That is to be expected, since `.forEach(...)` returns `undefined`.

Comment: "*I need to […] add this to form data.*" - where's your `FormData` object in the code, and how did you try to add something to it?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array, and then through the key -> value pairs of each object:

```js
let SHOCKS = [{
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "GBPUSD",
  D0: 0.3,
  D1: 0.3,
}, {
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "KRWUSD",
  D0: 0.3,
  D1: 0.3,
}, {
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "AUDJPY",
  D0: 0.08,
  D1: 0.08,
}, {
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "AUDKRW",
  D0: 0.08,
  D1: 0.08,

}, {
  $type: "Scenar",
  CCY_PAIR: "AUDMXN",
  D0: 0.08,
  D1: 0.08,

}];


SHOCKS.forEach((obj, idx) => {
  console.log("object " + (idx + 1));
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " + obj[key]);
    }
  }
});
```